# Getting error after setting sourceCompatility to 1.6 - Unsupported major.minor version 52.0

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, java-7, compatibility

I need to run a spring boot app jar. My machine is on java 1.8 but the destination server is on java 1.7.
Tried several things to generate a jar that will run on java 1.7. But nothing has worked so far.
I have tried 1.7, 1.6 and also 1.5. But none have worked.

build.gradle is as follows:

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = '2.2.6.RELEASE'
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath(
                "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
    }
}

plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.2.6.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
}
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'

/// ------------


compileJava {
    options.incremental = true
    options.fork = true
    options.failOnError = false
}

assert hasProperty('javaHome'): "Set the property 'javaHome' in your your gradle.properties pointing to a Java 6 or 7 installation"
assert hasProperty('targetJavaVersion'): "Set the property 'targetJavaVersion' in your your gradle.properties to '1.6' or '1.7'"

java {
    sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.toVersion(targetJavaVersion)
}

def javaExecutablesPath = new File(javaHome, 'bin')
def javaExecutables = [:].withDefault { execName ->
    def executable = new File(javaExecutablesPath, execName)
    assert executable.exists(): "There is no ${execName} executable in ${javaExecutablesPath}"
    executable
}

tasks.withType(AbstractCompile) {
    options.with {
        fork = true
        forkOptions.javaHome = file(javaHome)
    }
}
tasks.withType(JavaExec) {
    executable = javaExecutables.java
}

tasks.withType(Javadoc) {
    executable = javaExecutables.javadoc
}
tasks.withType(Test) {
    executable = javaExecutables.java
}


///--------
group = 'com.abc.grt'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '1.6'
targetCompatibility = '1.6'

jar {
    baseName = "someApp"
    version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter'
    compile "org.springframework.integration:spring-integration-sftp:4.3.7.RELEASE"
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.cloud/spring-cloud-context
    compile group: 'org.springframework.cloud', name: 'spring-cloud-context', version: '2.2.2.RELEASE'

    testImplementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test') {
        exclude group: 'org.junit.vintage', module: 'junit-vintage-engine'
    }
}


bootJar {
    baseName = "someApp"
    version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
    mainClassName = 'com.abc.grt.someApp.SomeApplication'
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

Destination machine throws the exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/springframework/boot/loader/JarLauncher : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
...
```

Comment: ["Spring Boot 2.2.6.RELEASE requires Java 8"](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/getting-started.html#getting-started-system-requirements)

Comment: I am using Spring Boot 2.2.6.RELEASE since I need to build an executable jar. I am using 'bootJar' for it. 'bootJar' is not available in older versions. Is there another way of creating an executable jar with an older version of Spring boot?

Comment: Huh? Spring Boot has supported executable jars since at least 0.5.0. But seriously, even Java 8 is EOL now; you _really_ need to upgrade your infrastructure.

Comment: The destination server is on Java 1.7, hence need it to be older version. So I have scaled back spring boot version to 1.5.9.RELEASE. Looking for a way to create an executable jar for the app.

Comment: It is _way_ past time to fix your server.